# Program must ask the user for an even integer max six times, if not it ends

Tags: python, numbers

The program ask the user for an even integer. If he asks for it 6 times, the program ends. If the number is even, it returns it. My code so far:

```
i = 0
for i in range(6):
    num = int(input("Num: "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
    else:
        num = int(input("Num: "))
        i+=1
        if i == 6:
            break
```

My program doesn't end after user gives 6 not even numbers, how can i fix this?

Comment: There's no need for the last `if`, since the `for` loop will stop by itself.

Comment: Why are you changing the loop variable `i` and check for the stop condition `i == 6` by yourself?

Comment: @Thornily in this case it stop after 12 inputs

Comment: @OSA__idk Yeah, looked at it again and then deleted the comment after I noticed i was wrong.

Comment: That's because do the input twice per iteration. Just remove the whole `else` part.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to check for `i == 6` yourself, this is done automatically by the `for` loop.

But you need to break out of the loop when an even number is entered.

```
for i in range(6):
    num = int(input("Num: "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print("Success!")
        break
else:
    print("Failure")
```

The `else:` block of a loop is executed if the loop reaches its normal conclusion instead of exiting due to `break`.

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(6):
    num = int(input("Num: "))
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(liczba)
        break
```

This will do what you want, without all the extra lines you had.